# Where is the root morpheme in Modern English abortion?

Tags: morphology, early-modern-english

The question is not so easy as it seems. Let's analyze some derivatives: abortion, abortive, abortiveness, abortionist. The analysis of derivational suffixes (-ion, -ive, ive+ness etc.) helps to identify the end of the root. But what about the prefix? Is it possible to consider ab- in this word as a negative prefix, as for example in ab-normal or ab-duct?

From etymological point of view the root must be OR (from L. abortivus "pertaining to miscarriage; causing abortion," from abort-, pp. stem of aboriri "disappear, miscarry," from ab- "amiss" (see ab-) + oriri "appear, be born, arise"). What about the root in Modern English (ort or abort) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you've already answered this question for yourself from the etymological point of view.

With regards to modern English, I wouldn't consider the *ab-* prefix to actually be a productive negative prefix of any kind. In the case of *abduct*, it's hard to argue that *ab-* is a negative prefix at all, especially since the stem *duct* is not obviously related in English to the meaning of *abduct*. You have to know Latin to make that connection. In the case of *abnormal* the *ab-* prefix does attach to an existing word *normal*, but its meaning here is simple lexical idiosyncracy.

So it is with *abortion*: I would argue that the stem *abort* is morphologically simple in English, with the Latinate prefix *ab-* being an unanalyzable part of the stem from a synchronic point of view. (And most English speakers have never heard of the word *ort*, and certainly wouldn't connect it in any way to the word *abort*.)

Comment: I agree. You could say that *a(b)* and *or(t)-* are the roots of this word, but those would be Latin roots, not modern English roots, according to modern definition: an English root is a root that is or once was used to create new words in modern English. One could argue that a word like *conortive* ("during birth") may be created in the near future by English academics and eventually become accepted; but then it will make more sense to say the word is created in modern Latin. Still, a case could be made.

Comment: Right. conortive is a nice example here for semantical criterion. But what about identification of roots in the following words: refer - prefer -confer - defer - transfer - infer or relate - collate - translate. We identify here morphemes independently of meaning, just compare these words with those of similar prefix-root structure. As for me, semantical criterion is not universal one for English, in those chains of words with similar prefix-root structure  distributional criterion serves better, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

*Ort* is an archaic word that means "a scrap or remainder of food from a meal." It derives from the Middle Low German *orte* ("food remains"), which originally was a compound word related to *eat*.
*Ab-* is a suffix that comes from Latin, that in English means "away; from."

In Modern English, *abort* is not composed from *ab* and *ort*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your examples. But what if we deal here (example from MLG orte is of Germanic origin) with homophones and etymological analysis proves that ab- in abortion has Roman origin with negative meaning.

Comment: @subic In Latin, the etymology of the word is _ab_ + _oriri_, but in English _abort_ is not _ab_ + _ort_.