# Very unusual meaning of "abortion"

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, meaning

The following use of the word "abortion" got my attention. It is from Graham Greene's *[The End of the Affair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_the_Affair)*, published in 1951. Here is the context:

> "...Listen. I met a man on the Common today with three legs."
>
> "How terrible," Henry said seriously. "An abortion?"

Most definitions of "abortion" I've checked focus mostly or exclusively on the termination of pregnancy which, at least in North America, is the most common meaning. There are a few definitions given which appear to correspond to Henry's use:

Merriam-Webster: MONSTROSITY (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abortion)

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_the_Affair): "2 an object or undertaking that is unpleasant or badly made or carried out."

And way down on this page on [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abortion?s=t&ld=1087): "6. a person or thing that is deformed"

But otherwise, as far as I can tell from the etymologies on the above links, and from [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28811/where-is-the-root-morpheme-in-modern-english-abortion), it looks as though the the word *abortion* has always referred to the early end to a pregnancy.

My question is, was Greene's usage ever common? I can't very well search Google Ngrams since it would be impossible to differentiate the intended meanings. Would a British reader in 1951 have made any association at all with an early termination to a pregnancy, when reading the exchange above?

Comment: I should add that I am quite sure no pun was intended. There was no reference anywhere in the book to childbirth, miscarriage, abortion (as more commonly defined today) nor to the Catholic church's stance on these matters.

Comment: Could it be a bastardisation of something abhorrent? ab-horrent ab-ortion? Just my fully uneducated wild guess ;)

Comment: Greene usage is OED's definition 3: *The imperfect offspring of an untimely birth, or any dwarfed and misshapen product of generation*, in the **literal** sense, which was probably relatively uncommon even in the 50s. But that definition continues with *hence fig. the nugatory or empty result of any action*, which has morphed into *an object or undertaking that is unpleasant or badly made or carried out* - a sense which has always been familiar to me since the 60s.

Comment: Thank God that not everything is searchable. I wonder if people don't find similar things in books in their own languages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Interesting :) But you can imagine that *monstrosity* is an extrapolation of the primary baby, miscarriage, blood and death definition. You actually *can* use Ngrams for this by searching for the term along with an appropriate adverb. In this case, I made an educated guess and searched for something along the lines of *[hideous abortion](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hideous%20abortion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)*, *ugly abortion* and similar. As you have noted, the frequency of usage has petered out in the last few decades, albeit, [not down to zero](http://www.fark.com/comments/4857437/Guy-Ritchies-abortion-of-a-film-known-as-Sherlock-Holmes-has-an-87-fresh-rating-on-Rotten-Tomatoes-Wait-what) :) The graph also indicates that it was still being used with relative regularity in the '50s.

A few examples excerpted from the results:

From *A sack of shakings* by Frank Thomas Bullen, 1901:

> She was everything that the Harbinger was not — *an ugly abortion* that the sea hated. When I first saw her (after I had shipped), I asked the cook whether she wasn't a razeed steamboat — I had almost said an adapted loco-boiler.

From *The French Revolution: The Bastille* by Thomas Carlyle, 1911:

> Miserable man ! thou " hast done evil as thou couldst " : thy whole existence seems one *hideous abortion* and mistake of Nature ; the use and meaning of thee not yet known.

and via [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abortion), from *Pictures of Italy*, [Chapter 10](http://etext.virginia.edu/etcbin/ot2www-pubeng?specfile=/texts/english/modeng/publicsearch/modengpub.o2w&act=text&offset=269656481&textreg=2&query=abortion&id=DicPict), by Charles Dickens, 1846:

> Insomuch that I do honestly believe, there can be no place in the world, where such *intolerable abortions*, begotten of the sculptor’s chisel, are to be found in such profusion, as in Rome.

Comment: Thanks 'beetle' -- great quotations. And extensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Coleopterist’s etymological hunch is correct: *abortion* comes from Latin meaning to terminate a pregnancy by accident (to miscarry) or by intent (in which more restricted sense *abortion* seems increasingly to be used).

My inclination would be to assume that Greene knew his craft well enough to pick his words wisely.  In addition to the sources coleopterist cites, you can find a contemporary review of [*Frankenstein*](http://knarf.english.upenn.edu/PShelley/frankrev.html) describing the monster as “an abortion and an anomaly”.

A quotation from [*The Godfather: Part II*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071562/quotes) gives a likely idea of how this metaphorical extension of meaning would have arisen.  “Just like our marriage is an abortion. Something that’s unholy and evil.”

Comment: Just a minor addition to the Latin etymology: the Italian equivalent of *abortion* is also used to indicate a failure in something we have done and likewise we use the verb in a figurative way to say that something has not reached its (foreseen) positive conclusion.

Comment: @Paola, thanks for the correction.  I’d misunderstood the etymology I’d checked, with regard to the meaning of the verb as opposed to those of its derived nominals.  For the curious, here’s the underlying verb: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aborior#Latin

Answer (score 2):

I have certainly heard the term used that way "in the wild". I had a co-worker who used to use it to characterize any badly-conceived (pun half-intended, I think) corporate policy.

In the USA at least, I think the word is so heavily and emotionally used in the political realm these days, that the other sense of it is perhaps falling by the wayside.

Comment: There are only 18 written instances of ["a bloody abortion"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+bloody+abortion%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22a+bloody+abortion%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&psj=1&ei=LgQPUL_xC-jL0QX0qIGoDQ&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=7ec3766e640e274a&biw=1306&bih=905) in Google Books, but most of them are for the *"complete mess"* sense - which I thought would be more common, since I seem to hear it quite often.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Well, that wouldn't catch any usage of the term in the USA, as the word "bloody" isn't really used here in any but the most literal sense. Any hit you got on those two words together in the USA would most likely be from extreme pro or anti-abortion groups.

Comment: I'm sure you're right. I believe Americans have long tended to avoid [all to cock](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35297/) in "polite society" in the belief that it's inherently crude, for similar reasons. But OED defines **abortion** as *The imperfect offspring of an untimely birth, or any dwarfed and misshapen product of generation; hence fig. the nugatory or empty result of any action*, and I have no problem with it. I expect pretty soon NASA will have to avoid saying *"Mission abort!"* (if and when the context arises again :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yeah, that particular four-letter word is also never used in a metaphorical sense here either. Instead, we use the "f-word" where you'd use that one. I don't believe there's any difference in crudity of the equivalent phrase here, we just don't use "cock" that way.

Comment: But the whole point is it's not really a "four-letter word" in *"all to cock"* - which I'd have been quite happy to use in front of my grandmother until she died a few years ago. I'd certainly *never* have said "fuck" in her hearing - in fact, I usually used to say *"Fiddlesticks!"* rather than *"Dammit!"* in her company, and I've no doubt she'd have ticked me off if I said *"Bloody hell!"* (which I bet I never did! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Perhaps I have the etymology of the term wrong then...I'd assumed it derived from the word's purient meaning (rather than the rooster, or some other source), and thus would be nearly as offensive in a phrase as alone. This would be a good subject of another question.

Comment: The etymology of *cock-up, all to cock* is in my link 4 comments above this one. In practice though, since many people (esp. Americans, I suspect) are unaware of it, the whole issue becomes irrelevant. Offence, like beauty, is in the mind of the perceiver, not the originator.

Answer (score 2):

In D. H. Lawrence's short story "The Daughters of the Vicar, (1911)" Lawrence has one of his characters use the word "abortion" to describe a sickly and frail person. He describes this person in the prose as "a small, chetif man, scarcely larger than a boy of twelve."
I believe that the common use of that time was to reference a disabled or severely underdeveloped person.

Answer (score 0):

> **abort**
> verb (STOP)   [ I or T ] to cause something to stop or fail
> before it begins or before it is complete:
>
> The mission had to be aborted at the last minute.
>
> If something goes wrong during the launch sequence the system will
> automatically abort.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abort

An abortion is what you have if the process of producing something stops before it is complete so the word can be applied to anything which appears to have gone wrong.